# Unchecked exceptions in Java: Inherit from Error or RuntimeException?

Tags: java, exception

I would like to handle errors with (unchecked) exceptions. I heared that for each kind of exception I should create a subclass of either Error or RuntimeException.
What's the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Errors`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) should identify programmatically unrecoverable problems (e.g. out of memory). [`Exceptions`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) should identify programmatically recoverable problems which are caused by unexpected conditions outside control of code (e.g. database down). [`RuntimeExceptions`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) should identify programmatically recoverable problems which are caused by faults in code flow (read: developer's faults such as null pointer, illegal argument, etc).

In your case you want to inherit from `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the JavaDocs kind of say it all:

> An `Error` is a subclass of
>   `Throwable`   * that
>   indicates serious problems that a
>   reasonable application   * should not
>   try to catch. Most such errors are
>   abnormal conditions.   * The
>   `ThreadDeath` error, though
>   a "normal" condition,  * is also a
>   subclass of `Error` because
>   most applications  * should not try to
>   catch it.

These are things like stackoverflow, out of memory...  you want to extend RuntimeException.

Answer (score 1):

Always use RuntimeException--I've virtually never seen a case for Error.

I've heard the same thing about creating your own exception though and I don't really understand it.  Often it's useful, but I use InvalidArgumentException ALL THE TIME.

Comment: Why not creating my own exception?
When I write a catch block I would like it to deal with a specific kind of exception, don't I?

Comment: From its Javadoc: *"This exception, designed for use by the **JCA/JCE engine classes**, is thrown when an invalid parameter is passed to a method."*. Don't you actually mean `IllegalArgumentException` to be more generic?

Comment: Yes, I do.  Crap.  I just wasn't thinking.  I'll go back and fix it.

Comment: You know, for an exception I throw nearly all the time, you'd think I would have gotten it right...  How embarrassing.

Answer (score 1):

RuntimeException is a special kind of Exception, Exceptions that compiler will not catch. Error is something that is thrown when there is some severe system problem. There is not a close relation between Error and RuntimeException. Yours seem closer to RuntimeException.